# definitions with fin types (lean)

Tags: math, theorem-proving, lean

I try to formalize a few statements about geometry with the help of the great mathlib. Unfortunately I'm running into some issues expressing my definitions.

```
import analysis.convex.basic
import analysis.convex.segment
import algebra.module.basic
import data.set.basic
import data.list.basic
import data.fin.tuple.basic
open set

section polygon
variables R M : Type*
variables [ordered_semiring R] [add_comm_monoid M] [module R M]

definition PolygonChain {n : ℕ} (V: list (M, M)) (P : set M):
  ∀ pair ∈ V, (segment pair.0 pair.1) ⊆ P 
end polygon
```

What I want to say is, given a list of vertex tuples from some vector space (extreme points of a polygon chain) and a set of points (that is supposed to be the whole polygon chain), then there must be a segment between the start and end vertex from every tuple, in the set of all points from the polygon chain.

I tried different ways to build the definition and noticed, that I seem to misunderstand `fin` related types, so a more elaborate explanation, would be appreciated. More specific an alternative definition was

```
definition PolygonChain {n : ℕ} (V: vector M n) (P : set M): 
  ∀ m ∈ (fin n), (segment (vector.nth m) (vector.nth m+1)) ⊆ P
```

I know that that the forall quantor is only applicable to types (so it doesn't really iterate over the range 0 < n), and saying that sth. is an element of sth. else, isn't a valid notation for that. Moreover how would I in general express statements about ranges and specific entries in vectors and lists?

Edit:
Thanks to Eric's answer I found the solution to the second definition

```
definition AltPolygonChain {n : ℕ} (v: vector M (n+1)) (P : set M): Prop := 
∀ m : fin (n), (segment R (vector.nth v m) (vector.nth v (m+1))) ⊆ P
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This at least fixes the *syntax* errors in your code:

```
import analysis.convex.basic
import analysis.convex.segment
import algebra.module.basic
import data.set.basic
import data.list.basic
import data.fin.tuple.basic
open set

section polygon
variables R M : Type*
variables [ordered_semiring R] [add_comm_monoid M] [module R M]

definition PolygonChain {n : ℕ} (V: list (M × M)) (P : set M) : Prop :=
  ∀ pair : M × M, pair ∈ V → (segment R pair.1 pair.2) ⊆ P

end polygon
```

Some remarks:

- `list (M, M)` should be spelt `list (M × M)`. `(a, b)` is a term of type `A × B`.
- The elements of a pair are `.1` and `.2`, not `.0` and `.1`.
- Projection notation (`.1`) only works if Lean already knows the type of `pair`.
- Segment needs an `R` argument.
- If you're *defining* a property, you want `def name : Prop := statement`. If the statement appears before the `:=`, then you're *proving* the statement.